# Redirect loop after setting up domains

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, http, amazon-s3, godaddy

I migrated domains from a service provider (ipage) to godaddy. The hosting has been setup on AWS S3. I have done such things before and they worked. However this time I'm hitting a redirect loop between `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` when I try to visit it via the browser.

Things I have done include:

1- Create and configure s3 bucket for mywebsite.com. The corresponding S3 url is X

2 - Create and configure s3 bucket for www.mywebsite.com and redirect it to bucket created in step 1 using S3 bucket properties.

3 - Add a CNAME record pointing www to X (from step 1).

4 - Add forwarding to the top level domain (mydomain.com) to direct to www.mydomain.com

```
nslookup www.mydomain.com

Server:         127.0.1.1                                                                                                                                     
Address:        127.0.1.1#53                                                                                                                                  

Non-authoritative answer:
www.mydomain.com        canonical name = mydomain.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com.
mydomain.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com    canonical name = s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com.
Name:   s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 203.83.221.121



nslookup mydomain.com
Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mydomain.com
Address: 184.168.221.8
```

Comment: Note that redirection issues are more closely related to webserver configuration than DNS.

Comment: What's your desired canonical domain, `www.mydomain.com` or `mydomain.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your redirection design seems to contradict each other, insofar ...

> 2 - Create and configure s3 bucket for www.mywebsite.com and redirect it to bucket created in step 1 using S3 bucket properties.

... redirect anyone accessing the [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket for `www.mywebsite.com` to `mywebsite.com`, whereas ...

> 4 - Add forwarding to the top level domain (mydomain.com) to direct to www.mydomain.com

... redirects anyone accessing the top level domain `mywebsite.com` to `www.mywebsite.com`

That should be easy to fix one way or the other, depending on what's the actual goal ;) - the [Example: Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) provides a complete walkthrough for an Amazon S3 bucket based on [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) zone apex support via [Alias Resource Record Sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingAliasRRSets.html).

Comment: Thanks! I realized this just after asking this and just swapping the buckets fixed it. I did not realize the S3 forwarding would forward to the domain and not the bucket name. Somehow I imagined that forwarding in S3 was only between buckets and did not hit the DNS.